# Get Hugo's version number in YAML files in Hugo v0.55

Tags: yaml, hugo

## Question

What's the right way to get Hugo's version number in locale files `i18n/*.yaml` under Hugo v0.55?

## Background

I'm using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) with the theme [Beautiful Hugo](https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo/), which included the following deprecated syntax since v0.55:

1. `.URL`
2. `.Hugo`
3. `.RSSLink`

#2 is used in locale files `i18n/*yaml` to get Hugo's version number `{{ .Hugo.Version }}`, but this is *deprecated*.

As a result, my terminal showed messages similar to this when running `hugo server`.

```
Building sites … WARN 2019/04/09 10:14:55 Page's .URL is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .Permalink or .RelPermalink. If what you want is the front matter URL value, use .Params.url.
WARN 2019/04/09 10:14:55 Page's .Hugo is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use the global hugo function.
WARN 2019/04/09 10:14:55 Page's .RSSLink is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use the Output Format's link, e.g. something like:
{{ with .OutputFormats.Get "RSS" }}{{ . RelPermalink }}{{ end }}.
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/chris-short/78582dc32f877d65eb388f832d2c1dfa

## Goal

How to suppress warning #2 `.Hugo`?  (I've already done #1 & #3).

## Attempt

@peaceiris on Qiita suggests [changing `{{ .Hugo.Generator }}` to `{{ hugo.Generator }}`](https://qiita.com/peaceiris/items/b6d611e184b2f28cc0ab).

[image: hugo generator new syntax]

Image source: [linked blog post](https://qiita.com/peaceiris/items/b6d611e184b2f28cc0ab)

I applied this to locales `i18n/*.yaml`.  i.e. I replaced `{{ .Hugo.Version }}` with `{{ hugo.Version }}` in those YAML files.  However, I got a *function "hugo" not defined* error.  I tested `{{ hugo.Version }}` in a Go-HTML template file, and it's OK.

```
Error: "/home/vin100/beautifulhugo/i18n/zh-TW.yaml:1:1": failed to load translations: unable to parse translation #14 because template: 由 <a href="http://gohugo.io">Hugo v{{ hugo.Version }}</a> 提供 &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 主題 <a href="https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo">Beautiful Hugo</a> 移植自 <a href="http://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/">Beautiful Jekyll</a>:1: function "hugo" not defined
map[id:poweredBy translation:由 <a href="http://gohugo.io">Hugo v{{ hugo.Version }}</a> 提供 &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 主題 <a href="https://github.com/halogenica/beautifulhugo">Beautiful Hugo</a> 移植自 <a href="http://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/">Beautiful Jekyll</a>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @bep on Hugo Discourse, I've found the soluton!  Simply use `{{ .Site.Hugo.Version }}`.

Reference: [@bep's answer on Hugo Discourse](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/show-hugos-version-number-in-yaml-file/18288?u=vincenttam)